# Want to create Favorite star in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-button, slds

I am having a left menu which will contain 50 menus. So we are planning to add a star so that users can add some menu as favorite. In order for that I am planning to use slds-checkbox-button. But I am not able to achieve star as back ground image as like below.

If I use rating kind of component then I can go for lightning-radio-group , since I am going to use only one star , I feel slds-checkbox-button is the only option.

I am not able to achieve this functionality. Any input would be helpful. I referenced this link

[here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox-button/)

[image]

Comment: So, it's an on-off "favorite" toggle or something?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show us the code you've tried so far and describe what is not working, including any errors verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own native component for this, such as:

## css

```
input {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + label:before {
  color: yellow;
}
input + label:before {
  content: '\2605';
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

## html

```
<template>
  <input id={name} type="checkbox" onchange={onchange}/>
  <label for={name}>
  </label>
</template>
```

## js

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Star extends LightningElement {
  @api set checked(value) {
    this.template.querySelector('input').checked = value;
    this._checked = value;
  }
  get checked() {
    return this._checked;
  }
  @api name;
  _checked;
  onchange(event) {
    this._checked = event.target.checked;
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent(
        'change',
          { detail: {
            name: this.name,
            checked: this._checked
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

See the [demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/rTV0h8wzO8iaY3JoHiNC/src/star.js).

This is only a basic version, you can add animations or whatever else you want, there's lots of examples out there on the Internet.